# Importing svg/png images from local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to load images from local storage but i have tried all options left on stackoverflow but not working yet.Below is the folder structure

[image]

And below is the code for `file-loader`

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
    },
},
```

**I tried using `import Star from '../images/star.svg';` and then `<img src={Star} alt="star" />`** but getting below error

`ERROR in ./client/images/star.svg
Module parse failed: C:\Users\muaz\Desktop\learn-redux - Copy\client\images\star.svg Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

And also tried `src={require("../images/star.svg")}` and getting same result.But i have already installed `file-loader` on dev depencies:

[image]

My full devServe.js code is

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    },
    // CSS
    { 
      test: /\.styl$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {},
    },
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Try this, does it work: `import my_icon_name from '../../images/filename.svg';` (change the paths) and then use it with `<img src={my_icon_name} />` This works for me using CRA and no other loader package.

Comment: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../images/star.svg`

Comment: Maybe this package will help instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader